# Spring Data Elasticsearch not give expected result

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring data elasticsearch to query in my elastic documents.

My Elasticsearch entity class:

```
@Document(indexName="keywords")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ESKeywords {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "text")
    private String text;
}
```

Indexed row in elastic search:

```
{
   "id": 118390,
   "text": "top 20 tweets of",      
}
```

For Example searching for "top 20 tweets of ABC".
It gives different results when I Use directly elastic search port it gives:
[image]

And with the code(ElasticsearchRepository.findByText()) it gives empty result.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just don't have one.

`keyword` field type should not be used for full text search - instead use `text`

Read also:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html

Comment: Edited the question please have a look once

Comment: when you change the @Field annotation, did you delete the index and ave it recreated by Spring Data Elasticsearch?